# Slack users.list api throwing invalid_auth error on passing of valid token as well

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I am creating one slack app. So there I need to fetch the team details. So I am calling `users.list` API. But it's throwing me an `invalid_auth` error.
I verified the token, my token is correct. When I am making request from slack's tester [tab](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list/test) it's returning me all the users list of team.

You can see in below image I am getting the correct response but my code is throwing me `invalid_auth` error.

[image]

Below is my code

```
 import request from 'request';
 const get = async (uri, token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request.get(`https://slack.com/api/users.list`, {
    qs: { token }
  }, (_, response) => {
    //some code
  });
});
```

What I am missing here?

As per Slack's documentation, `Either the provided token is invalid or the request originates from an IP address disallowed from making the request.` In my case token is correct, so do I need to add IP Address of machine ? if so, where to add it then ?

Would be great if someone can help me out here.

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar issue and couldn't figure out what is it all about. Adding token to Authorization header didn't work too.

Everything worked in the Slack tester, but a request from React would always got `invalid_auth`.
After inspecting the request that is sent from the Slack tester, I found it was sent as the form data. To mimic that, I did following:

```
  const bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append("token", data.access_token);
  bodyFormData.append("team", slackUser.data.user.team_id);

  const slackTeam = await axios.post(
    "https://slack.com/api/team.info",
    bodyFormData,
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    }
  );
```

That was successful.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some changes in Slack API authorization.

Instead of passing **token** as query parameter, 
 pass it as **authorization header.**

[image]